# Global objects of Managed types

Tags: c++-cli, global-variables, managed-c++

Is there any way to declare/define global/static objects of managed types ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although you can have static methods and members in managed code, .NET does not have any concept of a global or completely static object.  You can have a class with all static members (and in C#, it can be called a static class, but this is a compiler construct).

However, you can effectively do this via [Singletons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) in C++/CLI.  The same issues that exist with [Singletons in C#](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/singleton.html) map to C++/CLI when dealing with managed classes.